# What is the best way to implement the versioning for ASP.NET WebAPIs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What is the best approach to version WebAPIs?

I am building an API from scratch and I would like to ensure that it will version gracefully in the future. I am envisioning something like mysite.com/api/v2/...

One approach I see is to create a separate project (web app) for each version of API. But perhaps there are better ways to do it?

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including version number in the URL is the standard approach as I explained in this post (I do not repeat the content): [Implementing versioning a RESTful API with WCF or ASP.Net Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592078/implementing-versioning-a-restful-api-with-wcf-or-asp-net-web-api/10599004#comment13910301_10599004)

You do not need to create a completely new project although you can. The problem that you will be facing with a single project is that there will be collision of names:

> /api/v1.0/Car/123

and

> /api/v2.0/Car/123

both will point to `CarController` while you can have only one of those. The solution would be to implement your own `IHttpControllerSelector` and register with the DependencyResolver. This implementation will look at the version number and perhaps find the type based on the namespace.

---

## UPDATE

I do not intend to start a REST controversy here. But as @DarrelMiller points out, here is an older discussion on the same subject **discouraging** my suggested approach:

[How to version REST URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris/975394#975394)

I *personally* think URL versioning is the way to go.

Comment: I can assure you that most REST advocates will argue strongly against versioning in the URL like that.

Comment: @DarrelMiller so what is your view? Can you please share it with us?

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks. I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for response. So it seems that having a separate project for each version is the most straightforward and hassle-free approach?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create your own implementation of `IHttpControllerSelector`. The best way is to base this implementation on Microsoft's `IHttpControllerSelector`. Then you can decide in your `IHttpControllerSelector`if you want to version by URL or by content-type.

The most basic implementation directly implements `IHttpControllerSelector` and just implements the `SelectController` method but performance reasons it is better to implement some caching around it.

For finding the Controller you simple the `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` instance you can get using `HttpConfiguration.Services`.

I've used something like this: http://damsteen.nl/blog/implementing-versioning-in-asp.net-web-api. Also put some code on Github: https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.